# iOS equivalent of accessing Android asset files

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, assets

I have a Xamarin Android application in which I've bundled up some files as assets and I can access them like this: `Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(fileName))`.

How would I go about doing this in an iOS application?

Comment: include them in your project as "Content" and then just open them using normal File IO operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NSBundle` class is the closest equivalent with using a `BundleResource` build action:

#### Example:

```
var path = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
var filePath = Path.Combine(path, "someDataFile.xml");
var someFileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

There are also `FromBundle` overloads on some classes:

```
var image = UIImage.FromBundle("myimage.png");
```